# PostgreSQL dump and restore

Tags: postgresql, windows, pg-dump, pg-restore

I can't seem to dump/restore on Windows with my database. Lines used and error messages:

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres --format=c -O -d ue > latest.dump
pg_restore -h localhost -U postgres -d ue latest.dump
```

Getting this error,

> pg_restore: [archiver] input file does not appear to be a valid archive

With this,

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U postgres -O -d ue > latest.dump
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d ue -f latest.dump
```

I get this error,

> psql:latest.dump:1: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xff

I'm completely stumped. Most of the search results relate to not using the correct `pg_restore`/`psql` with the file type exported by `pg_dump`, but as you can see above, I've accounted for that.

`latest.dump` seems to be filling up correctly, at least in the plain format it exports SQL that I can read and is the correct export of the database.

Comment: Have you FTPed it between machines in ASCII mode instead of binary?

Comment: How do I change the export mode besides `--format=`? Also, not sure what FTP has to do with it. This simple case dumps and tries to restore to a local Postgresql install. No networking involved.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently the problem was the `>` operator. Changing that to `-f` to specify the file for the dump, resolved the problem (using the plain format).

I was writing a Powershell script which may have been the underlying cause. The commands were accepted, but there could have been a corruption issue there.

Comment: The problem here is that Windows's command-shell I/O redirection is not 8-bit clean. I'd like `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` to refuse to read from and write the terminal, but I don't know how to detect it without preventing other safe uses of stdio/pipes.